# Exporting Parts of mesh

Tags: mesh

Hello is there anyway to export parts of a mesh only and not the whole thing.For example.I have a chest piece that is made on one character mesh.I can duplicate that chest piece off of that mesh.But I want to export that chest piece only,for another character in a totally different file.How can I do that, please help?.And I like to thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik no, but it could also depend on the specific exporter, since they are all independent (made differently).

eg: the collada exporter has a specific option.

[image]

The simplest way to get what you need is to save your file, then create a new empty blend file and import in it from the saved file where you have only what you want (eg chest piece).

Then, even without saving the new file, export from that new file to th eformat you need (eg: obj, dxf, fbx, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way, first make another (save as) of your project so you can work on it without loosing it while doing the way i will talk about, then select every thing you DON'T WANT to export and delete it, then export the rest of it, it must be done this way ;-)